# Boole's inequality proof

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

[image]

About the first approach, $P(A\cup B)\le P(A)+P(B)$ bc $(\mathcal{E, B}, P)$ is a probability space, so in fact since $P$ is a measure the $P(A)+P(B)=P(A\cup B)$ only if $A$ and $B$ are disjoint o.w. $P(A)+P(B)>P(A\cup B)$. Then by induction we have that $P\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^N B_i\right)\le\sum_{i=1}^N P(B_i)$ for any number $N$.

(1.1) says if $C_1\subset C_2\subset\dots$ are increasing measurable sets then $\mu\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty C_n\right)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \mu(C_n)$.

I don't see the connection between the two results.

What I tried: We can write $B_1,B_2\dots$ increasingly by creating $C_n=\bigcup_{i=1}^nB_i$. The result from induction says $P\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^N B_i\right)=P\left(C_N\right)\le\sum_{i=1}^N P(B_i)$. Now take the limit on the inequality to get $\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}P\left(C_N\right)\le\sum_{i=1}^\infty P(B_i)$ but from (1.1) the left part is just $P\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty C_n\right)=P\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty B_n\right)$.

Is this right?

Comment: Yes, this is right (I think you wanted to write $P$ instead of $\mu$). Note that $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty C_n=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty B_n$.

Comment: It's not true that $A\cap B\ne \emptyset$ implies $P(A)+P(B)>P(A\cup B).$

Comment: @nejimban thank you for confirming!

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Oh, you are so right! I guess, $A\cup B=A\cup (B-A\cap B)$, so $\mu(A\cup B)=\mu(A)+\mu(B-A\cap B)\le \mu(A)+\mu(B)$ for that part